# Create new ID based on cumulative sum in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I need to create a new transport ID based on the cumulative sum of the volume being transported. Let´s say that originally everything was transported in truck A with a capacity of 25. Now I want to assign these items to shipments with truck B (Capacity 15).

The only real constraint is amt shipped cannot exceed capacity.

I can´t post a picture because of the restrictions...but the overall set up would be like this:

```
Old Trans # Volume  New Trans # Cumulative Volume for Trans

1   1       
1   9       
1   3       
1   7       
1   4       
2   9       
2   10      
3   8       
3   5       
3   9       
4   4       
4   6       
4   8       
5   9       
5   1       
5   5       
5   8       
6   3       
6   4       
6   3       
6   4       
6   4       
6   7       
7   7       
7   10      
7   4       
8   10      
8   6       
8   7       
9   4       
9   9       
9   6       
10  7       
10  4       
10  1       
10  1       
10  5       
10  2       
11  9       
11  3       
11  9       
12  8       
12  5       
12  9       
13  9
```

Expected output would be that the first three entries would result in a new shipment ID of 1;the next two entries would result in a new shipment ID of 2;and so on... I´ve tried everthing that I know(excluding VBA): Index/lookup/if functions. My VBA skills are very limited though.Any tips?? thanks!

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsItD.png]

Comment: Please add some sample input, along with expected output.  In addition, what exactly have you tried so far?

Comment: post picture with fake data, just to see what you trying to achieve (example what you have and what you need)

Comment: I added some more details, but I cannot post a picture to to account restrictions.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Reading [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) will help you get an answer sooner. Remember, this isn't a code-writing service, so post what you've got & we can help you fix it.

Comment: What is the intended result if a single shipment is over the capacity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see what you're trying to do here, and just using an IF formula (and inserting a new column to keep track):

[image: Example]

In the Columns C and D, insert these formulas in row 3 and copy down (changing 15 for whatever you want your new volume capacity to be):

Column C: =IF(B3+C2<15,B3+C2,B3)

Column D: =IF(B3+C2<15,D2,D2+1)

And for the cells C2 and D2:

C2: = B2

D2: = A2

Is this what you're looking to do?

Comment: Worked like a charm for 10000 entries! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple formula could be written that 'floats' the range totals for each successive load ID.

In the following, I've typed *25* and *15* in D1:E1 and used a custom number format of *I\D 0*. In this way, the column is identified and the cell can be referenced as a true number load limit. You can hard-code the limits into the formula if you prefer by overwriting **D$1** but you will not have a one-size-fits-all formula that can be copied right for alternate load limits as I have in my example..

[image: Floating SUM load limit]

The formula in D2 is,

```
=IF(ROW()=2, 1, (SUM(INDEX($B:$B, MATCH(D1, D1:D$1, 0)):$B2)>D$1)+ D1)
```

Fill right to E2 then down as necessary.